# Blur Effect in Flutter for whole Application

Tags: flutter, dart

Here, I made the flutter application that is transparent and now I want it to be blur. The background screen we see from the application (i.e., windows) should be seen with the blur effect. If anyone have the idea on how to, please share. I research a lot but the packages such as GlassMorphism and other ways such as BackDropFilter does not work for this question.

**Things to consider for the answer of this question**
I meant blur not opacity. There is difference in blur and opacity. Blur is for example: just as BackDropFilter Gives to the Image. Opacity is different. If i really wanted what opacity provided then i wouldn't have asked the question, as i have already used to make it transparent. Plus, I hope the voters would think twice about it.

I would be really thankful for the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [flutter_acrylic](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_acrylic) might help you. You can play with WindowEffect.aero & WindowEffect.acrylic to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try this, i looks like it will work.

Comment: this seems to work macos and some features in windows 11 but it is dead when tested with window 10, are there any other ways to make it happen? that is compatible for atleast different version of windows and macos?

Comment: if (macos || win11) {WindowsEffect.Acrylic;} else {WindowEffect.Aero}. Beside this conditional option, I do not see any other solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75382630/change-application-opening-animation-in-flutter
Do you have any idea on the matter described in the given link?

Answer (score 0):

Use background color property with `opacity`.

```
backgroundColor : Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
```

More Detail : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/withOpacity.html

Comment: I meant blur not opacity, thanks.
There is difference in blur and opacity. Blur is for example: just as BackDropFilter Gives to the Image. Opacity is different.
If i really wanted what opacity provided then i wouldn't have asked the question, as i have already used to make it transparent.
Plus, I hope the voters would think twice about it.

Comment: Okay. Screenshot looks like need to opacity to page that's why I suggest opacity.