# Change application opening animation in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, animation, flutter-animation

Below is the link of the natural behavior flutter desktop application shows in my application:

https://screenrec.com/share/wtcI6OFJ7L

Because this is the system tray application for desktop, to give the feel, i want it to open as:

https://screenrec.com/share/FfJknUReT3

How can it be achieved? The animation plugins in flutter that i have researched so far does not provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is only about windows platform, I found a WIN32 API that may meet your needs.

Follow this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow

Here is a YouTube video on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meIci7gOTLk

You can call the api using win32 package in your flutter application. Here is the link: https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/winrt/AnimateWindow.html

As per its documentation, the API enables you to produce special effects when showing or hiding windows. There are four types of animation: roll, slide, collapse or expand, and alpha-blended fade.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).